# How can I display a Gtk Widget over (inside) a Cairo surface?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, cairo, gtk3, pycairo

I have a GTK widget named Cloud (which basically subclasses Gtk.Eventbox) as a Cairo surface painted with a SVG. I'm trying to display other Gtk widgets (Label/Buttons) over it.

I tried adding Gtk.Label elements to the Cloud but they are not shown over the surface.

Using Gtk.Fixed and to position the Cloud under the label doesn't work either.

How do I draw a Gtk widget on a Cairo surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what a Cloud GTK widget is; but more generally, you can use a [`Gtk.Overlay`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkOverlay.html). `add()` the cloud widget as its main child, then `add_overlay()` the other widgets.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's just a GTK widget named Cloud. Thanks!